# Change CLI's php

Tags: symfony, command-line-interface

Im working with Symfony2. Im trying to execute the following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Could not create database for connection named <comment>symfony</comment>
could not find driver
```

APC is already installed, since the `Symfony/web/config.php` was OK, what I realised is that the version of php from CLI is different from the one Apache is running.

The one Apache is running has APC installed, so I would like CLI to run that same php, How can I do that?

Comment: In Gentoo there is a `eselect php list cli` and `eselect php list apache2` tool to set the PHP version. What distro are you using?

Comment: Thanks, in my case deleting the version that macports installed was enough to have CLI and Apache run the same PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case deleting the version that macports installed was enough to have CLI and Apache run the same PHP.

And that's:

```
sudo port uninstall php5
```

Comment: So if you removed php5 what you got left? Another php5 package installed by another package manager (homebrew, fink)?

Comment: In my case the php that was installed by default on Lion OSX